# What's the easiest way to anchor some text to an external link using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

inside my HTML page I add some text using this:

```
<script>
    $('.description').text('my description')
</script>
```

Inside `my description` I need to place an anchor tag href to an external link like this: `<a href="http://link_to_website.com">link to a website</a>`

How could I proceed using jQuery to achieve something like this?

Comment: Its time to learn [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: So you mean to say on specific position ?

Comment: @MokshShah I need it inside `.text('my description')`

Comment: simply you can by `.html('<a href="yoursite.com"> my description</a>')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to do this:

```
$('.description').text('my description').append($('<a />', {href:"http://linkofhref", text:"text goes here."}));
```

Check the demo below:

```js
$('.description').text('my description ').append($('<a />', {href:"http://linkofhref", text:"text goes here."}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='description'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
   $('.description').html('<a href="http://link_to_website.com">link to a website</a>')
```

or

```
$('.description').html('my description <br> <a href="http://link_to_website.com">link to a website</a>')
```

Comment: thanks, but I need also the text description...could I concatenate?

Comment: yes you can concat it directly inside quotes of parameter in html

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.description').html('<a href="http://link_to_website.com">link to a website</a>');
});
</script>
```